# Terraform: Tagging AWS Lightsail instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-lightsail

Given the Terraform [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lightsail_instance.html) on AWS Lightsail, I can  construct a Lightsail instance as follows.

```
resource "aws_lightsail_instance" "my_ls_instance" {
  name              = "my_ls"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1b"
  blueprint_id      = "ubuntu_18_04"
  bundle_id         = "2xlarge_2_0"
  key_pair_name     = "MyKeyName"
}
```

### It is possible to tag a Lightsail instance using Terraform?

Tagging is not mentioned in the documentation.
I tried adding the following, which did not work.

```
  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terraform providers are a bit behind the current Lightsail feature set, and tagging is one of the newer features - which is to say, it doesn't work at this time.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Do you know if AWS CloudFormation supports tagging / create-from-snapshot for Lightsail?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't any support of Lightsail in CloudFormation - this is an area I'm really trying to push on (IAC) - your best option for tagging right now is to use the AWS CLI - which means you're mixing tools, but it's the only way to script it right now.